# Need to add a child with value in Firebase using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase img]

I need to insert in my Firebase using AngularJS a new child with value 0.

I try to insert using this command but doesn't work:

```
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
objectname = "name";
$scope.insert= ref.child("user/"+objectname);
$scope.insert.setvalue("Arthur");



result expected
firebaseID 
    |-------------user
                   |-----name:Arthur
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing it the Angular way. 
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md

---

You could use Three-way Data Bindings:

```
  var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["firebase"]);

  // a factory to create a re-usable Profile object
  // we pass in a username and get back their synchronized data as an object
  app.factory("Profile", ["$firebaseObject",
    function($firebaseObject) {
      return function(username) {
        // create a reference to the database node where we will store our data
        var ref = firebase.database().ref("rooms").push();
        var profileRef = ref.child(username);

        // return it as a synchronized object
        return $firebaseObject(profileRef);
      }
    }
  ]);

  app.controller("ProfileCtrl", ["$scope", "Profile",
    function($scope, Profile) {

      //your object id
      var objectId = '-KSe_RHPYjhkjasjjh-o6';  
      // create a three-way binding to our Profile as $scope.profile
      Profile(objectId).$bindTo($scope, "profile");

      //now simple manipulate the $scope.profile variable
      $scope.profile.name = "Arthur";
    }
  ]);
```